# How to Grab Specific Text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to grab the price of bitcoin from this website: https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin
but I am not sure how to do it, i'm pretty new to coding.

This is my code so far, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin')
r_content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_content, 'lxml')

p_value = soup.find('span', {'class': "currency-price", "data-value": True})['data-value']

print(p_value)
```

This is the result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/aidan/PycharmProjects/scraping/Scraper.py", line 8, in
>   
>       p_value = soup.find('span', {'class': "currency-price", "data-value": True})['data-value'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is dynamically sourced from an API call returning json. You can use a list of currencies or a single currency. With `requests` javascript doesn't run and this content isn't added to the DOM and various DOM changes, to leave html as seen in browser, don't occur.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://production.api.coindesk.com/v1/currency/ticker?currencies=BTC').json()
print(r)
price = r['data']['currency']['BTC']['quotes']['USD']['price']
print(price)
r = requests.get('https://production.api.coindesk.com/v1/currency/ticker?currencies=ADA,BCH,BSV,BTC,BTG,DASH,DCR,DOGE,EOS,ETC,ETH,IOTA,LSK,LTC,NEO,QTUM,TRX,XEM,XLM,XMR,XRP,ZEC').json()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `soup.find()` call is not returning a value (that is, there is no `span` with the attributes you have defined on the page) therefore when you try to get `data-value` there is no dictionary to look it up in.

Answer (score 0):

your website doesn't hold the data in html, this way you can't scrape it, but they are using an end point that you could use:

```
data = requests.get('https://production.api.coindesk.com/v1/currency/ticker?currencies=BTC').json()
p_value = data['data']['currency']['BTC']['quotes']['USD']['price']
print(p_value)

# output: 11375.678380772
```

the price is changing all the time so my output may be diffrent

Comment: Cheers mate, so basically I can't scrape it because it isn't even in HTML so I have to source it from the API?